# PHP cannot write to text file

Tags: php

I have the following code which I am using in WordPress/Woocommerce:

```
function generatePassword($length = 6) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$pass = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
$pass .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $pass;
}

$password = generatePassword();

$data = "\n" . $password . ',' . time();

$test = 'http://advokatami.bg/ot/a/docs/test/test.txt';
$file = fopen($test,"a");
fwrite($file,$data);
fclose($file);
```

And it works except for the final part where it has to write to a file. Can you tell me what is wrong with the code? I tried changing the CHMOD, but no success.

Comment: You cannot write a file at a web address, you can only write a file on the server where PHP is running.

Comment: Enable error reporting and see what the problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/391/exception-handling-and-error-reporting#t=201608311201584997097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide Web server path of actual file location path in your server instead of url.

```
$test = 'http://advokatami.bg/ot/a/docs/test/test.txt';
```

Replace it by Server path

```
$test = '<location_of_your_webroot_folder_in_server>/ot/a/docs/test/test.txt';
```

Make sure `test` have permission for read and write publicly.

#### How can you check your folder path?

1) Make `test.php` file in `ot` folder with below code

```
<?php
echo dirname(__FILE__);
die();
```

2) Upload it in `ot` folder.

3) execute file from browser `http://advokatami.bg/ot/test.php`

4) Copy path before `\ot\....` and replace it on `<location_of_your_webroot_folder_in_server>`.

Comment: Check my edits for steps how to get file path on server